# Division for SDIV and UDIV in ARM Cortex-M4 processor?

Tags: arm, cortex-m, integer-division

Problem:

Distance = 1195172 / (n - 1058)

I am given this formula to help me convert a ADC value to a distance. My n value has to be 2552 <= n <= 16383 as my minimal input is 2552 and max input is a 14bit value(16383 in dec). What i am told is that I have to use a SDIV to do the division in the formula.

Why can't I use UDIV instead of SDIV in the formula?

From what I understand is that SDIV is used when there may be a possible case where my division output is a negative number, however given my n input range, that seems impossible. Am i missing out on something on division in a Cortex-M4 processor?

Comment: **What i am told..** told by who/what; a compiler?  Can you give the code where the issue occurs?

Answer (score 2):

> Am i missing out on something on division in a Cortex-M4 processor?

The processor and instruction set has nothing to do with it.

```
.thumb_func
.globl test1
test1:
    udiv r0,r0,r1
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl test2
test2:
    sdiv r0,r0,r1
    bx lr
```

call it (hexstring just prints out the thing passed)

```
hexstring(test1(1195172,2552-1058));
hexstring(test2(1195172,2552-1058));
hexstring(test1(1195172,16383-1058));
hexstring(test2(1195172,16383-1058));
```

result

```
0000031F 
0000031F 
0000004D 
0000004D
```

1195172 = 0x0012485C

16383-1058 = 0x00003BDD